# Trainable decision tree? A decision tree that relearns decision boundaries based on new examples?

Tags: machine-learning, cart, online-algorithms

Trainable decision tree? A decision tree that relearns decision boundaries based on new examples?

Does this exist?

Application:

I can draw good boundaries on the data I have based on intuition, but it's possible that future observations would lead to readjusting of these boundaries, when there comes cases in which the boundaries would lead to a different outcome than what the observed outcome is.

There are few references on "SVM partitioned support vector machines". But results seemed mixed.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incremental_decision_tree

Comment: There's a [Python implementation](https://pypi.org/project/incremental-trees/).